# How can I declare a scalar variable to be acceptable to SQL Server/LINQPad?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linqpad, scalar

I'm trying to run a T-SQL query in LINQPad, and referenced [this page](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-137.aspx) about declaring variables, but get this:

[image]

What is missing in how I'm declaring and assigning vals to these variables?

I could just replace the assignments, such as:

```
cmonth = @Cmonth
```

...with:

```
cmonth = 4
```

...but there are several places in the query where this value is referenced, and I don't want to replace them all every time I test a different set of data.

So what is wrong or missing in how I'm doing this?

Comment: Try to remove GO before your Select statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `GO` statements. Each chunk of SQL runs as a batch on it's own until the next `GO` statement. If you want to use those variables they need to be in the same batch as the statements that use them.

Short answer is to remove the `GO` statements.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I just looked at your link. There is nowhere in that article that they show a snippet that does a `DECLARE` to make a variable, and then has a `GO` between that line and where it is used. They do have a snippet that has 2 batches that do nothing but declare unused variables, but I think that's just to show syntax. The next snippets `DECLARE @DateFormat INT` and use them in the same batch.

Comment: And one more point: There are times that you'll want to run a script that *has* to have multiple batches. Let's say you want to have a `CREATE PROCEDURE`, then a script that uses it 6 times, then you want to `DROP PROCEDURE`. A proc has to be created in it's own batch, so you'll need a `GO` after that. Then you can use it in a batch, and then you'll drop it in a batch. I don't see any examples in your link where they need batches though.